# Не объявляется глобальная переменная

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вот код:

```
var testval = 'test';
function getip(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/utils.php",
        data: "id=getip",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                testval = data;
            } else {
                console.error('undefined');
            }
        }
    });
}
getip();
alert(testval);
```

Вместо того чтобы вывести реальный айпи выдаётся test. Если сделать просто переменную выдаётся undefined. Поясните, что я делаю не так? Научите делать правильно) Буду признателен)

Comment: это асинхронный запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция `getip` асинхронная. Это означает, что результат оной будет через какое-то время. В то же время, вызов `alert(testval);` последовательный. К этому моменту ваш ajax запрос ещё не был отправлен и в `testval` хранится значение по-умолчанию.

Можно, например, так:

```
function getip(callBack){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/utils.php",
        data: "id=getip",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                callBack(data);
            } else {
                callBack('undefined');
            }
        }
    });
}
getip((ip) => {
     // здесь у вас уже будет правильный ip
     alert(ip);
});
```